# Encrypted wallet which is syncronizing

Tags: wallet

I have a question, I have like 0.1 BTC on my wallet from FEB 2013.

I am 34 weeks behind sync with bitcoin-qt wallet, but the weird thing is its encrypted but I think that i never encrypted it.

Is it possible it says its encrypted because its out of sync? or it is encrypted?

and also if u set a bitcoin password can it be something like: hello123 (the reason for asking is because maybe I can figure it out) if its something hard I probably wont remember it (randoms chars, e.g symbols).

EDIT: thing also is that in the menu I cannot choose encryp wallet ..

Answer (score 1):

If it says the wallet is encrypted, then it's encrypted. I can't imagine any way the wallet could be encrypted other than that you encrypted it. You can try as many passwords as quickly as you want, so maybe you'll remember it.